# Digital Ocean ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, express, digital-ocean, dokku

I have a dokku droplet set up on digital ocean.

Since updating dokku, I am unable to git push to it (I've tried with three different apps - all fail for the same reason). I receive the following error.

```
    remote: + usermod --home /app herokuishuser
    To example.com:redisapp
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@example.com:redisapp'
```

My app is written in node.js / express and I was able to push it before I updated dokku. I have enabled logging - which reveals the following. I can't make head nor tail of it - so need some insight into what could be going wrong?

```
    Robs-MacBook-Pro:redis_app rob$ git push dokku master
    Counting objects: 1589, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (1540/1540), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (1589/1589), 1.85 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 1589 (delta 314), reused 0 (delta 0)
    -----> Cleaning up...
    -----> Building redisapp from herokuish...
    -----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
    remote: + [[ -d /tmp/app ]]
    remote: + cmd-export paths
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=paths as=paths
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=paths
    remote: + cmd-export version
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=version as=version
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=version
    remote: + cmd-export herokuish-test test
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=herokuish-test as=test
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ ++ ++ sortgrep
    remote: -v :
    remote: for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=herokuish-test
    remote: + cmd-export-ns buildpack 'Use and install buildpacks'
    remote: + declare ns=buildpack 'desc=Use and install buildpacks'
    remote: + eval 'buildpack() {
    remote:         declare desc="Use and install buildpacks"
    remote:         cmd-ns buildpack "$@";
    remote:     }'
    remote: + cmd-export buildpack
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=buildpack as=buildpack
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=buildpack
    remote: + CMDS["$1"]=buildpack
    remote: + cmd-export buildpack-build
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=buildpack-build as=buildpack-build
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + echo buildpack-build
    remote: + ns=buildpack
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=buildpack-build
    remote: + cmd-export buildpack-install
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=buildpack-install as=buildpack-install
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + echo buildpack-install
    remote: + ns=buildpack
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=buildpack-install
    remote: + cmd-export buildpack-list
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=buildpack-list as=buildpack-list
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ ++ grep -v :
    remote: sort
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:install
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + echo buildpack-list
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + ns=buildpack
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=buildpack-list
    remote: + cmd-export-ns slug 'Manage application slugs'
    remote: + declare ns=slug 'desc=Manage application slugs'
    remote: + eval 'slug() {
    remote:         declare desc="Manage application slugs"
    remote:         cmd-ns slug "$@";
    remote:     }'
    remote: + cmd-export slug
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=slug as=slug
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ ++ sort
    remote: for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:install
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:list
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + echo slug
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=slug
    remote: + CMDS["$1"]=slug
    remote: + cmd-export slug-import
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=slug-import as=slug-import
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:install
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:list
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + echo slug-import
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + echo slug-import
    remote: + grep '^slug-'
    remote: + ns=slug
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=slug-import
    remote: + cmd-export slug-generate
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=slug-generate as=slug-generate
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:install
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:import
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:list
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + echo slug-generate
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^slug-'
    remote: + echo slug-generate
    remote: + ns=slug
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=slug-generate
    remote: + cmd-export slug-export
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=slug-export as=slug-export
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ ++ sort
    remote: grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:install
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:generate
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:import
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:list
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + echo slug-export
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^slug-'+ echo slug-export
    remote:
    remote: + ns=slug
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=slug-export
    remote: + cmd-export-ns procfile 'Use Procfiles and run app commands'
    remote: + declare ns=procfile 'desc=Use Procfiles and run app commands'
    remote: + eval 'procfile() {
    remote:         declare desc="Use Procfiles and run app commands"
    remote:         cmd-ns procfile "$@";
    remote:     }'
    remote: + cmd-export procfile
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=procfile as=procfile
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:install
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:generate
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:import
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:list
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:export
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + echo procfile
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + + echo procfile
    remote: grep '^slug-'
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=procfile
    remote: + CMDS["$1"]=procfile
    remote: + cmd-export procfile-start
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=procfile-start as=procfile-start
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :procfile
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:install
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:generate
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:import
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:list
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:export
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo procfile
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + echo procfile-start
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + echo procfile-start
    remote: + grep '^procfile-'
    remote: + ns=procfile
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + + echo procfile-start
    remote: grep '^slug-'
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=procfile-start
    remote: + cmd-export procfile-exec
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=procfile-exec as=procfile-exec
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ ++ echo sort
    remote: :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :procfile
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:install
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo procfile:start
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:generate
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:import
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:list
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:export
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo procfile
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + + echo procfile-exec
    remote: grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + echo procfile-exec
    remote: + grep '^procfile-'
    remote: + ns=procfile
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^slug-'
    remote: + echo procfile-exec
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=procfile-exec
    remote: + cmd-export procfile-parse
    remote: + declare 'desc=Exports a function as a command'
    remote: + declare fn=procfile-parse as=procfile-parse
    remote: + local ns=
    remote: ++ cmd-list-ns
    remote: ++ sort
    remote: ++ grep -v :
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :version
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :help
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :procfile
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:install
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo procfile:start
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :test
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:generate
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :paths
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo :slug
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:import
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:list
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo slug:export
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo buildpack:build
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo procfile:exec
    remote: ++ for k in '"${!CMDS[@]}"'
    remote: ++ echo procfile
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^buildpack-'
    remote: + echo procfile-parse
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^procfile-'
    remote: + echo procfile-parse
    remote: + ns=procfile
    remote: + for n in '$(cmd-list-ns)'
    remote: + grep '^slug-'
    remote: + echo procfile-parse
    remote: + CMDS["$ns:${as/#$ns-/}"]=procfile-parse
    remote: + case "$SELF" in
    remote: + buildpack-build
    remote: + declare 'desc=Build an application using installed buildpacks'
    remote: + ensure-paths
    remote: + mkdir -p /app /tmp/env /tmp/build /cache /tmp/buildpacks
    remote: + [[ -n herokuishuser ]]
    remote: + buildpack-setup
    remote: + export APP_DIR=/app
    remote: + APP_DIR=/app
    remote: + export HOME=/app
    remote: + HOME=/app
    remote: + export REQUEST_ID=build-3197
    remote: + REQUEST_ID=build-3197
    remote: + export STACK=cedar-14
    remote: + STACK=cedar-14
    remote: + cp -r /app/. /tmp/build
    remote: + usermod --home /app herokuishuser
    To example.com:redisapp
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@example.com:redisapp'
```

If I SSH into the server, and run `dokku apps` I see the app listed. I destroy it, and try again. I see the app listed again.

It seems to fail when adding BUILD_ENV to build environment.

I have spent the last two hours googling, and tried all sorts of things from increasing the available memory, through to setting environment variables - none of which work.

I have also deleted both remote and local git repositories and set them up again - this didn't work.

Does anyone have any advice or guidance on where I should look?

** Edit **

I have updated the server so its running the latest of everything. Cleaned up docker and updated dokku. still fails to work.

Answer (score 0):

Purely by accident, I stumbled upon: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ubunutu-dokku-docker-apt-get-update-issue

> This has been confirmed to be a bug in Dokku. You can view the issue on GitHub.

Upgrading buildstep will resolve the problem:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/progrium/buildstep.git
$ cd buildstep
$ git pull origin master
$ sudo make build
```

It's the last comment on the list. I don't know why this works.. I'm assuming its because when I updated dokku a bunch of stuff wasn't carried forward? Putting this here an an answer - but I don't consider it correct, as it lacks explanation. So it wont get the tick.

@JoseDiaz-Gonzalez  - thanks for your message in the comments. Attached log file here.

```
root@xxx:/# apt-get install herokuish
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
herokuish is already the newest version (0.3.18).
herokuish set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libclass-accessor-perl libfcgi-perl libio-string-perl libsub-name-perl libsystemd-journal0
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up dokku (0.7.2) ...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/tr...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/tr...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fi...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fi...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ko...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ko...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/da...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/da...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/pt_BR...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/pt_BR...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/nb...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/nb...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ro...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ro...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/hu...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/hu...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/vi...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/vi...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/id...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/id...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/pl...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/pl...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/uk...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/uk...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sv...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sv...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/zh...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/zh...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sl...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sl...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/es...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/es...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/it...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/it...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/eo...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/eo...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/pt...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/pt...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sk...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sk...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ja...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ja...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/de...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/de...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/hr...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/hr...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/zh_CN...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/zh_CN...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/zh_TW...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/zh_TW...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/cs...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/cs...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sr...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sr...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/el...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/el...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ru...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ru...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/nl...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/nl...
Purging old database entries in /usr/local/man...
Processing manual pages under /usr/local/man...
0 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
0 manual pages were added.
0 stray cats were added.
0 old database entries were purged.
docker:x:999:dokku
Setting up storage directories
Setting up plugin directories
Migrating old plugins
Enabling all core plugins
find: File system loop detected; ‘/var/lib/dokku/core-plugins/available/named-containers/named-containers’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/var/lib/dokku/core-plugins/available/named-containers’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘/var/lib/dokku/core-plugins/enabled/named-containers/named-containers’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/var/lib/dokku/core-plugins/enabled/named-containers’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘/var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/named-containers/named-containers’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/named-containers’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘/var/lib/dokku/plugins/enabled/named-containers/named-containers’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/var/lib/dokku/plugins/enabled/named-containers’.
dpkg: error processing package dokku (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dokku
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Dokku hasn't used buildstep in quite a while, so if this solves your problems, then you are using an ancient version of Dokku, and haven't actually been running the latest of anything. We user herokuish now, and I believe the issue is that you haven't upgraded herokuish via `apt-get install herokuish`.

Comment: @JoseDiaz-Gonzalez Thanks... I've just ran apt-get install herokuish and it says I'm using the most up to date version? But I told it to install anyway. I'll paste the log above. Is Herokuish a replacement for dokku?

Comment: Herokuish is the underlying docker image we use to simulate heroku. It's a replacement for buildstep, which provided the same interface.